# React: How to change opacity of element by clicking button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to change the opacity of `headerInside` element using React.

I came up with this idea, but with use of the vanilla JS.
How to write it using React hooks?

```js
const menuHandler = () => {
  const element = document.querySelector('.headerInside');
  
  if (element.style.opacity === "1") {
    element.style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
    element.style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
```

The `return()` section looks like this:

```html
<header>
  <button onClick={menuHandler} className="brgr">test</button>
  <div className="headerInside">
    ...  
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zrna's answer got the point. I wanna change it a little .

```
...
     <button onClick={() => setOpacity(1-opacity)} className="brgr">test</button>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using React hooks:

```js
const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0);

return (
  <header>
    <button onClick={() => setOpacity(1)} className="brgr">test</button>
    <div style={{ opacity }}>
      ...  
    </div>
  </header>
);
```

Comment: Can You explain why it works like that? I really don't get the ,,style={{ opacity }}" part. How it knows that it has to setup opacity to 1?

Comment: @NatanKrakowiak it's an abbreviation if property and variable have the same name.  
`style={{ opacity: opacity }}` == `style={{ opacity }}`